# looping over items and access property of a parsed json object

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

OK i know how to parse using newtonsoft.
but I don't know how can i get every value of key inside parsed string

this is the json encoded string

```
{"result":[{"orderid":"94","imei":"clipper"},{"orderid":"93","item":"shoes"},{"orderid":"92","item":"bag"},{"orderid":"91","item":"shirt"}]} 

Dim xreadingJson = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(htmlcode)
Dim resultorder As String = xreadingJson.Item("result").ToString
```

then the result order is

```
[
{
"orderid": "94",
"item": "clipper"
},
{
"orderid": "93",
"item": "shoes"
 },
 {
"orderid": "92",
"item": "shoes"
  },
 {
"orderid": "91",
"item": "bag"
  }
 ]
```

On looping how can I get the value of orderid and item.
thank you

**Update:**
I resolved it using this code

```
        Dim o As JObject = JObject.Parse(htmlcode)
        Dim results As List(Of JToken) = o.Children().ToList
        For Each item As JProperty In results
            item.CreateReader()
            'MsgBox(item.Value)
            If item.Value.Type = JTokenType.Array Then
                For Each subitem As JObject In item.Values
                    MsgBox(subitem("orderid"))
                    MsgBox(subitem("item"))
                Next
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Newtonsoft's JObject has a JObject.GetValue("property_name") method

Comment: But how can i loop the result oder to get the property name value